# increase partition /temp or use root partition on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using a server in aws for my website developed in ruby on rails 5 with passenger and nginx, everything has been working perfect until today, it has been showing me the following error `/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/libexec/rbenv-init: line 131: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device`

I execute the following command `df -h` and it shows me the following:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.0G   12K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs           396M  364K  395M   1% /run
/dev/xvda1       26G   15G  9.5G  62% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
overflow        1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /tmp
```

and when use `tail -f log/production.log` into the project, it shows me the following error:

```
I, [2020-02-21T18:50:38.283374 #12760]  INFO -- : [5636754d-ca36-43f2-afcf-b0a025d3adca] Started GET "/" for 190.198.232.67 at 2020-02-21 18:50:38 +0000
I, [2020-02-21T18:50:38.284158 #12760]  INFO -- : [5636754d-ca36-43f2-afcf-b0a025d3adca] Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
D, [2020-02-21T18:50:38.285317 #12760] DEBUG -- : [5636754d-ca36-43f2-afcf-b0a025d3adca]    (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users`                                                                                               
D, [2020-02-21T18:50:38.355268 #12760] DEBUG -- : [5636754d-ca36-43f2-afcf-b0a025d3adca]    (69.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, `users`.`city` AS users_city FROM `users` GROUP BY `users`.`city`                           
I, [2020-02-21T18:50:38.355476 #12760]  INFO -- : [5636754d-ca36-43f2-afcf-b0a025d3adca] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 71ms (ActiveRecord: 69.6ms)
F, [2020-02-21T18:50:38.356099 #12760] FATAL -- : [5636754d-ca36-43f2-afcf-b0a025d3adca]   
F, [2020-02-21T18:50:38.356136 #12760] FATAL -- : [5636754d-ca36-43f2-afcf-b0a025d3adca] ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Error writing file '/tmp/MYkVaUQs' (Errcode: 28 "No space left on device"): SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, `users`.`city` AS users_city FROM `users` GROUP BY `users`.`city`):
F, [2020-02-21T18:50:38.356157 #12760] FATAL -- : [5636754d-ca36-43f2-afcf-b0a025d3adca]   
F, [2020-02-21T18:50:38.356179 #12760] FATAL -- : [5636754d-ca36-43f2-afcf-b0a025d3adca] app/controllers/home_controller.rb:12:in `index'
```

I've been looking for a way to increase that temp partition or find some way to make the operating system no longer take that temp partition and save the temporary files in the root, according to this [page](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1431169) I could do this by modifying the /etc/fstab file but inside it I don't see the temp partition specified. only this:

```
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /    ext4   defaults,discard    0 0
/dev/xvdb   /mnt    auto    defaults,nobootwait,comment=cloudconfig 0   2
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a very strange filesystem layout.   1mb for /tmp is tiny.

Have you checked what's actually on the filesystem in /tmp?

To be honest, if you're not familiar with linux, your easiest migration path is to spin up another server that doesn't have a separate /tmp, and migrate your services to the new server.